# Adding multiple `Helpers` to template file

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to add multiple helper in `hbs` file. But getting error. Can't I add multiple helpers?

```
<span class="label-value">{{is-empty-value convert-to-currency card.balances.current-balance}}</span>
```

1. card.balances.current-balance : number value getting
2. convert-to-currency : converting to currency
3. is-empty-value : adding hyphen if value is empty

I have written helpers for some other reasons; now I am trying to use all together, but it does not work. It is only considered as empty values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a helper within a helper (called [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions)), you need to use parentheses around the inner helper:

```
<span class="label-value">{{is-empty-value (convert-to-currency card.balances.current-balance)}}</span>
```